# MySQL query for ID < variable

Tags: php, mysql

Hey, so what I am looking to accomplish is a MySQL query which grabs just the FIRST row whos ID is less than my current one. So basically a next button. Here is what I would like to modify:

```
$next = mysql_query("select * from posts where id<'$id'");
```

So how would I change this so it only selects the first value which is less than my ID value (which is the id of my current page)

Thanks! I will be doing this the reverse way for a previous button too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from posts where id<'$id' order by id desc limit 1
```

This will get you the first id smaller than the provided parameter  `$id`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$next=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id<'{$id}' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: If you mean the closest idea which is smaller than your $id, use ORDER BY id DESC